# standalone settings for a c# dll - updated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, config, settings.settings

I have searched for a while quite fruitlessly for a way to do this.

I am working on  a project the has many parts, most of which i can not directly access, but it is extensible. So I have written a dll for it,  but the problem is that I need to be able to supply some sort of settings/config that can be updated with out having to recompile the dll.

I don't have access to a main exe's app.config. and the settings/dll.config that vs2010 creates is not being picked up by the dll.

Is this actually possible? a standalone operational config file for a dll?

#### new update.  - I have created a settings.settings file and the all successfully picks up the config data but it seems to bake it into the file when its compiled, when i edit the config after deployment it does not pick up the changes. I tried the first answer below and it didn't work.

thanks

Comment: Could make a little XML config file that your DLL reads from to set various settings.

Comment: You should rather check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0 I hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [System Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx) namespace you can create a ConfigurationSection which can be used to store any configuration properties you like:

```
public class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyProperty")]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)this["MyProperty"] }
        set { this["MyProperty"] = value;
    }
}
```

Then in your assembly project you can read your assembly specific configuration. If your assembly is called MyAssembly, then GetSection() will look for a configuration file called MyAssembly.dll.config:

```
var myConfig = (MyConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionName");
Console.WriteLine(myConfig.MyProperty);
```

I didn't try this specific example, but I have had to do this before. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused why this got downvoted. Isn't this what the asker is looking for?

Comment: not sure why it was down voted either. but it unfortunately doesn't fix the issue. please update above